# How to test AlertDialog item click in Robotium for Android Studio

Tags: java, android, robotium

I have an AlertDialog as below, I don't know how to test it with Robotium in Android Studio. Can anyone give me a hint for that?

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Select");
            final String[] items = {"Take a picture using carmera", "Choose a picture from Album"};
            alertDialogBuilder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    if (i == 0) {
```

...
...

Answer (score 2):

See [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257104/robotium-system-dialogs#answer-19056578):

> This works for me:
>
> ```
> solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(android.R.id.button1));
> ```
>
> where the 'Positive' button is android.R.id.button1, the 'Negative'
>   button is android.R.id.button2 and 'Neutral' is android.R.id.button3.

It means that for your `AlertDialog` you would need to use the `solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(dialogId))` method.

Check out also [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375456/handle-random-dialogs-using-robotium#answer-14381300):

> lets say you have some code like this
>
> ```
> solo.clickOnView(view1);
>
> solo.clickOnView(view2);
> ```
>
> and you know the dialog can appear between these two steps of your test, you can place in code that is something like:
>
> ```
> if(solo.waitForView(dialogView, 1000, false)){
>     solo.clickOnView(dialogDismissButton);
>     solo.clickOnView(view2) //retry the step above
> }
> ```

Comment: Can you explain how this relates to the code in the question?

Comment: Great, I have edited a bit more for you (hyperlinks inline and quote from second link).